# Is the number of foldtext dashes incorrect?

Tags: folding

Ref to :h foldtext()

`The number of leading dashes depends on the foldlevel.`

As follow, I think the foldlevel of `printf` is 1.

[image]

But, you can see as follow, the number of dashes is 2.

[image]

I can't understand why inconsist

Answer (score 2):

The documentation does not say how many dashes are there per foldlevel. As can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f080d70a82f3a4477f346d9efcdfaec1bc1e1d58/src/evalfunc.c#L3989-L4002):

```c
txt = NGETTEXT("+-%s%3ld line: ", "+-%s%3ld lines: ", count);
r = alloc((unsigned)(STRLEN(txt)
        + STRLEN(dashes)        /* for %s */
        + 20            /* for %3ld */
        + STRLEN(s)));      /* concatenated */
if (r != NULL)
{
    sprintf((char *)r, txt, dashes, count);
    len = (int)STRLEN(r);
    STRCAT(r, s);
    /* remove 'foldmarker' and 'commentstring' */
    foldtext_cleanup(r + len);
    rettv->vval.v_string = r;
}
```

So you can see, the number of dashes is actually equal to the **foldlevel + 1**

Comment: But why foldlevel+1?
I feel this is not convenient by default.

Comment: Why? That is a question I cannot answer. It's what it is

Answer (score 1):

As @Christian Brabandt showed from the source code, the string used for folding has a "+-" at the beginning of the string, resulting in the `foldlevel+1` dashes. I can't answer whether this is intentional or a bug. You could [open an issue on the vim github](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/new) if you feel that this is a bug, and you will hopefully receive either justification for the extra dash or the "bug" will be fixed.

If you would like a "fix" for this, you can add the following to your vimrc:

```
function MyFoldText()
    let line = getline(v:foldstart)
    let sub = substitute(line, '^\s*\|//\s*\|/\*\|\*/\|{{{\d\=', '', 'g')
    let oneLessDash = strpart(string(v:folddashes),1,len(string(v:folddashes))-2)
    let foldlinecount = foldclosedend(v:foldstart) - foldclosed(v:foldstart) + 1
    let lineCount = " " . string(foldlinecount) . " lines: "
    return "+" . oneLessDash . lineCount . sub
endfunction
set foldtext=MyFoldText()
```

This will print the same `foldtext` as before with just one less dash.

P.S. Welcome to the community!